# PHP Code Sniffer not Picking up File, Class and Function Doc Comments

Tags: php, phpcodesniffer

I'm working on implementing PHPCS into my build scripts and have resolved all ERROR and WARNINGS with relative ease (and a little help from SO :)).

However, I cannot figure out why I'm still getting an ERROR saying the class is missing file, class and function doc comments.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 FOUND 7 ERRORS AFFECTING 7 LINES
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   2 | ERROR | Missing file doc comment
  28 | ERROR | Missing class doc comment
  45 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
  59 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
  73 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
  88 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
 102 | ERROR | Missing function doc comment
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the PHP class:

```
﻿<?php
/**
 * EndpointHelper File Doc Comment
 * 
 * @category    EndpointHelper
 * @package     Helper
 * @author      Brian Smith <brian.smith@company.com>
 * @copyright   Copyright 2015 Company, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 * @link        http://arctg.com
 */

/**
 * EndpointHelper Class Doc Comment
 * 
 * Endpoint Helper to retrieve application wide
 * URLs based on active webinstance.
 * 
 * @category    Class
 * @package     EndpointHelper
 * @author      Brian Smith <brian.smith@company.com>
 * @copyright   Copyright 2015 Company, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE
 * @link        http://company.com
 * 
 * @since   1.0.1
 */
class EndpointHelper
{
    /**
     * Component params object
     * 
     * @var type 
     * @since   1.0.1
     */
    private static $params = false;

    /**
     * Retrieve Reservation URL based on web instance
     * 
     * @return String
     * 
     * @since   1.0.1
     */
    public static function getReservationUrl()
    {
        $instance = self::getInstanceType();

        return self::$params->get($instance . '_reservation_api_url');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Rental URL based on web instance
     * 
     * @return String
     * 
     * @since   1.0.1
     */
    public static function getRentalUrl()
    {
        $instance = self::getInstanceType();

        return self::$params->get($instance . '_rental_api_url');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve cache URL based on web instance
     * 
     * @return String
     * 
     * @since   1.0.1
     */
    public static function getCacheUrl()
    {
        $instance = self::getInstanceType();

        return self::$params->get($instance . '_data_cache_api_url');
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve Systems Staging File Sync URL based on web
     * instance.
     * 
     * @return String
     * 
     * @since   1.0.1
     */
    public static function getFileSyncUrl()
    {
        $instance = self::getInstanceType();

        return self::$params->get($instance . '_file_sync');
    }

    /**
     * Private utilty class to retrieve current web instance
     * 
     * @return String
     * 
     * @since   1.0.1
     */
    private static function getInstanceType()
    {
        if (!self::$params)
        {
            self::$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_custom');
        }

        return self::$params->get('web_instance');
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was tied to the ruleset I was using from Joomla.  I recently took another stab at getting it to work and the author of the Wiki had updated the article stating you needed to use a specific version of PHP Docs.

Purging the existing install and installing the version listed resolved the issue for me.